# Using >> operator stop my stringstream to get chars from a file stream

Tags: c++, stringstream, ostringstream

```
   //I know it is bad using (namespace std) but I'm editing a "attached project"
   // as exercise from my Professor.

   //All required libraries: iostream, fstream, sstream, stdlib are included.

   stringstream stringas;
   ifstream fromfile;
   string nickname;
   float points;

      nickname="";
      points=0;
      fromfile.open ("top10.txt", ifstream::in);

      cout << "Testing contents from file : " << endl;

      while (fromfile.good()){

          if((char) fromfile.get() != '|' )
           {
                fromfile.unget();
                stringas << (char) fromfile.get();
           }
           else
           {
               if(nickname=="")
               {
                nickname = stringas.str(); 
                //or i want use stringas >> nickname;
                stringas.str(string()); 
               }
               else
               {

                stringas >> points; 
                //Problem starts here (when I use >> operator)
                //then I extract all chars from "ss object"
                //Why i can't get Others chars from file when 
                //while(fromfile.good()) starts again?

                stringas.str(string());

               cout << "Nickname: " << nome << endl;
               cout << "Points: " << points << endl;

               topplayers.insert(nickname,points); 
               //topplayers is a Custom(mine) Linked List of 
               // struct type {string nicks,float scores} defined in private
               // in a class(where there is this function).

               }

           }

      }

fromfile.close();
```

Help me to understand what is happening when I use >> operator of a stringstream
and why I cannot re-use << operator after.

I'm a Italian student, sorry for my bad English.

I  know that I can make parsing with delimiters from a file in other ways, but I need a simple way, without using too many variables and library such as Boost.

EDITED FOR MORE DETAILS:

top10.txt file contains:

```
t04d|120|simon|240|
```

ouput:

```
Testing contents from file:

Nickname: t04d
Points: 120
```

Application run without errors,but obviously don't print on screen

```
Nickname: simon
Points: 240
```

That I expected;

Comment: Applies to good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong